# Laravel $this in User-Model returns first User, not logged in user (sporadically )

Tags: laravel, methods, model, this, non-static

I think I have a logic or syntax problem here.

In a controller I use:

```
$signature = auth()->user()->email_signature($language);
```

In user model I use:

```php
public function email_signature($language='de')
{
    $signature_name = $this->name;
}
```

So sometimes `$this->name` returns Name of first User in User-Table, not logged in User. Whats the problem here? `$this` seems to be the whole table and not just the `auth()->user()` Record :(

And the worst part: it happens sporadically :(

session is database based in .env

Comment: This is an interesting issue, but it just doesn't sound _right_. I suggest that you use Laravel's Log of `$this` within the `email_signature`. That way, you can find out what the value is during runtime. At the moment, I don't think we have enough information to go on.

Comment: Does `User` model extend `Authenticatable` class? I wish you would provide more details of the `User` model codes?

Comment: log is a nice idea, i will try this... thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry, this is my first post here :D

User model is as it is by default

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable   {
use HasFactory, Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
];
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

and so on

... can one say that $this in a non-static method is ALWAYS and DEFINATELY the one model, i call the function with? because thats what i thought and relied on... obviously its very critical, if the wrong user returns... even worse in permission methods...

Answer (score 0):

my mistake, the error was something completely else... $this returns correct user, as it should be.

thanks anyway!!! :D

i can rely again on my user functions!